# Aurelia-Kendo multiselect - how get selected values in viewmodel?

Tags: kendo-ui, aurelia, multi-select

I has the following code in html-file:

```
<ak-multiselect k-data-text-field="name" 
  k-data-value-field="id"
  k-data-source.bind="corporateGroupDataSource" 
  k-on-change.delegate="SetGroupFilter($event, 'GroupId')"
  data-placeholder="Select corporate group...">
</ak-multiselect>
```

By button press I will create filter from all existing multiselects on the html-page and will send request to database.
But how I can get selected values of multiselect in my viewmodel? I mean js-file...

I can't use *id* of multiselect.

Comment: Post the JS you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `k-value.two-way="yourVMVariableName"` to bind to the value. More information can be found here: http://aurelia-ui-toolkits.github.io/demo-kendo/#/samples/multiselect-basic-use